# Webpack TypeScript module.hot does not exist

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, webpack-hmr

I want to enable **Webpack HMR** in a **NodeJS** project written in **TypeScript**.

But `module.hot` is not available:

- **@types/webpack-env** defines:

  ```
  declare var module: __WebpackModuleApi.Module
  ```
- Which conflicts with **@types/node** definition:

  ```
  declare var module: NodeModule
  ```

Removing **@types/node**, solves the issue, but disables `process`:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' // [ts] Cannot find name 'process'
```

Comment: A typo: `@type/webpack-env` should be `@types/webpack-env`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### Conflict resolution

**@types/webpack-env** was since updated:

- Conflict on `module` was solved in [this PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/13741)
- `process` was added in [this commit](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/c0cba20b9f2e44c8b679c88d58aa30d69d3d272c)

The code in the original question now only needs **@types/webpack-env**.

But importing **@types/node** alongside won't conflict anymore.

---

### Installation

```
npm install --save-dev @types/webpack-env
```

And if you also need NodeJS environment definitions:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

Answer (score 55):

As few guys wrote here it's the best way:

```
npm i -D @types/webpack-env
```

For me it works as expected, resolving issue with not recognized `hot` property.

In my project I'm using those versions:

```
"@types/node": "^8.0.19",
"@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.0"
```

I don't know if question is still up to date but for my problem installing types for webpack help me.

Comment: This worked for me, without any other additions.

Answer (score 25):

Could be as simple as adding following line at the top of the file.

```
///<reference types="webpack-env" />
```

Comment: This works for me after installing the typings for webpack-env:
npm install --save-dev @types/webpack-env

Comment: this is very weird but worked for me in NX development https://nx.dev/ 
I installed first `@types/webpack-env` and later your reference line on the top of file. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can augment the global scope and use interface merging to reopen the `NodeModule` interface and add the missing `hot` property.

```
import webpack = require("webpack");

declare global {
    interface NodeModule {
        hot: {
            accept(dependencies: string[], callback: (updatedDependencies: string[]) => void): void;
            accept(dependency: string, callback: () => void): void;
            accept(errHandler?: (err: any) => void): void;
            decline(dependencies: string[]): void;
            decline(dependency: string): void;
            decline(): void;

            dispose(callback: (data: any) => void): void;
            addDisposeHandler(callback: (data: any) => void): void;

            removeDisposeHandler(callback: (data: any) => void): void;
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

But really, this augmentation should potentially be done in the Webpack declaration file itself.

Comment: Yes I thought there would be an official solution, with a definition available somewhere.

Comment: You can absolutely send a PR and we'll accept it if the API is appropriate. I mostly wrote the answer up based on what I could find from the current documentation. Would you consider this the accepted answer otherwise?

Comment: In fact everything is well defined in `@types/webpack-env`, it was an error from my side as I added `@types/node` to be able to use modules and require and I should not have.

Comment: I updated my question as I'm now facing issues with `process`.

Comment: Adding `@types/webpack-env` worked out for me. I suppose We do not have the same libs imported.

Comment: @AdrianMoisa The type definition conflict was solved at the time of your message. That's why everything worked so well. :)

Answer (score 4):

Change .hot by ['hot']

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    module.hot.dispose(() => {
```

Use

```
if (module['hot']) {
    module['hot'].accept();
    module['hot'].dispose(() => {
```

Comment: This is a much better solution, since simple === better.

Comment: @Bartekus This is not a good solution. It does not solve the conflict issue, and disables type-safety.

Answer (score 4):

**This fixes it**

`yarn add @types/webpack-env --dev`

VScode would work immediately

Intellij would need a restart